# how to add undo manager for multiple UIView

Tags: ios, iphone

I need some idea to how perform undo opertaion with UndoManager.

In my app user can add as many gifts (UIView) on a screen. He can rearrange & resize all added gifts on that screen.

For adding, rearranging & resizing gifts, I have made a subclass of UIView & in that class I have implemented code for the same operations on touch delegates.

Now my question is that if user has rearranged multiple gifts & also resize some of them, how I can implement a undomanager to restore all the gifts in original position.

Any idea or suggestion would be great at this time.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have run into EXACTLY same problem.

Comment: @Sha
I have tried to implement & added my work on github.com/Gagan5278/UndoManager Might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to undo the change of position, size & rotation of `UIViews`, you need to hold the frame, transform of it when the gesture started. So that when perform undo, you can revert to the initial values.

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029093/nsundomanager-to-undo-uiimage-rotation-using-rotation-gesture)

Comment: Can you please provide some detail on the answer? Any code to explain?