# NSUndoManager for multiple UIViews - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, undo-redo, nsundomanager

My `ViewController` has multiple `UIViews` in it. User is able to resize/move the `UIViews` by dragging them. I have implemented this by subclassing `UIView` and using touch delegates.

No I want to implement `NSUndoManager` to undo the last operation which occurred on any `UIView`. How to do that?

I'm pretty new to `NSUndoManager`. My problem is same is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180072/how-to-add-undo-manager-for-multiple-uiview), but I don;t understand the answer to that question.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple undo managers. The `undoManager` property of your view controller will do fine. Basically, the idea is: whenever a user resizes/moves one of your views, you calculate the corresponding transformation/move that would revert this action and add this information to the undo manager. Then, when a user performs an `undo` action, the rotation/resize is reverted.

Have a look at this question for an example: [NSUndoManager to undo UIImage rotation using rotation gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029093/nsundomanager-to-undo-uiimage-rotation-using-rotation-gesture)

Comment: Having a central undo manager has different functionality than a separate one for each view. Consider, for example, a drawing app. The app uses multiple layers, each of which can be drawn on separately. The layers have curves with various thicknesses, opacity, etc. By having a separate undo manager for each layer, the user can perform undo operations specific to the layer they are interested in. With a central undo manager, if they do work on one layer, then work on a second layer, then they can't undo the work on the first layer without undoing the second one first.